# iOS - opposite of nil for rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I need to make a button reappear after I set it to nil but I can't seem to figure it out.

I set it to `nil` using:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =nil;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you set the button to nil you destroy (deallocate) it. Just recreate the button. Or, if it's expensive to create for some reason, create another property which holds the button and then use that to restore the `rightBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Thanks, is there another way to hide the button? I tried add a button at the end of a table view but it wont let me connect an outlet to the button only the view/table view, this is only an issue on the iPad and not the iPhone which I find strange.

Comment: In viewDidLoad you can store the rightBarButtonItem (created in the XIB) into another property.

Answer (score 2):

It's a requirement to set the button to nil? Another approach is to set the button's background alpha to 0, or disable it with setEnabled:NO. If it's a requirement, you have two options:

- Store the button as a property and assign the button to the rightBarButtonItem of the navigationItem. Make sure you do all button manipulation to the property.
- Create a method to create an instance of UINavigationItem with the button and assign this button to rightBarButtonItem. By the way, if you want to have exactly the same instance you had in the nil assignment, you must use the first option.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is the way I would go

Comment: Thanks, its not a requirement to set it to nil. What I was going for was once a certain action has been completed such as registration then the button would disappear. I tried adding a normal button from IB to the end of a table view however it will not let be attach an outlet to it, it will only allow me to attach the outlet to the table view (this is an issue I've found only on the ipad as ive the same application on the iphone and it works no problem. I took your approach and setEnabled to No after registration.

Comment: nice, if this solved your problem, please mark my answer!
Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton animated:YES]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is how to restore the original button that was in place before being set to `nil`.

Comment: True. Read the q too quickly :P

Answer (score 0):

Hide the button by setting the reference to nil, however if you want to restore it later, you'll need to hang onto a copy of it so you can reassign it.

```
UIBarButtonItem *oldButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
[oldButton retain];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

//... later
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = oldButton;
[oldButton release];
```

Or create a property of the barbuttonitem and just pass it whenever you need it.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *rightNavButton;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightNavButton;
```